# MariaDB performance according to CPU Cache

Tags: mariadb, cpu, cpu-cache

I want to build a `MariaDB` server.
I am researching `DB` performance according to `CPU` specification before server purchase.

Are there any benefits to gaining as `CPU Cache` changes from `8MB` to `12MB`?

Is it a good option to purchase a large `CPU Cache`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Don't pay extra for more cores.  MariaDB essentially uses part of only one core for each active connection.

Don't pay extra for faster CPU or anything else to do with the CPU.  If you do become CPU-bound, then come back here for help with optimizing your query; it is usually as simple as adding a composite index or reformulating a query.

Throwing hardware at something is a one-time partial fix and of low benefit -- a few percent: like 2% or, rarely, 20%.

Reformulation or indexing can (depending on the situation) give you 2x or 20x or even 200x.

More RAM *up to a point* is beneficial.  Make a crude estimate of dataset size.  Let us know that value, plus some clue of what type of app.

SSD instead of HDD is rather standard, but that *may* give noticeable benefit.